# Does ${\rm Tr}(ABC) = {\rm Tr}(ABC')$ imply ${\rm Tr}(C) = {\rm Tr}(C')$ for matrix polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

As the title says, if for (not necessarily invertible) matrices $A,B,C,C'$ if we have

$$
Tr(ABC) \;\; =\;\; Tr(ABC')
$$

does this imply $Tr(C) = Tr(C')$?  The only thing I can imagine doing is subtracting one side from the other to obtain $Tr(AB(C-C')) = 0$, but how can we argue that the trace of $C-C'$ is zero?  Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit**

I need to drastically change what I wrote here: Suppose $A, C,$ and $C'$ are in fact nonzero matrix polynomials with $B$ invertible.  We can therefore write $A =A(\lambda), C = C(\lambda), C' = C'(\lambda)$ for a variable $\lambda$.

Comment: Making $A$, $C$, $C'$ be matrix polynomials is no help.  You could still have $A (C - C') = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Why should it? Take $A=B=0,$ and take any $C,C'$ you like.

**Edit**: Regarding your edit, instead let $B$ be $I_2$ (the $2\times2$ identity matrix), $A$ be any non-zero $2\times2$ matrix such that $A^\dagger=-A$ (which can be considered a constant matrix polynomial), $C$ be any non-zero $2\times2$ matrix polynomial you like, and $C'=C+I_2.$ Clearly, $C,C'$ do not have equal trace, but you should be able to show that $AB(C-C')$ has trace $0$.

Comment: My question was actually too vague how I originally wrote it.  Take a look at my edits if you feel like it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your edit. However, I will remark that your edit seems less a matter of clearing up vague wording, and more like a complete alteration of the stated conditions. It probably would have been better to leave this post as it was, and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. What if $Tr(AB)=0$? Or even worse, what if $AB=0$?

---

For your edited question: Take $B$ to be the identity matrix. You essentially asking if $$Tr(AC)=0$$ does it imply $Tr(C)=0$, which again, is far from possible.

Comment: My question was actually too vague how I originally wrote it. Take a look at my edits if you feel like it.

Comment: Hmm, would you please elaborate on what happens if $Tr(AB)=0$?